# How can I cycle through each member of a structure variable?

Tags: c, struct, reflection

This code is just a simplified version of what I'm looking for. Generally I'd like to know how to access any type of variable, so maybe I could type `horse[6]` to access an `int`, and `horse[7]` to access a `char` as well.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct horse_s{
    int age;
    int height;
    int width;
    int weight;
}horse;

struct horse_s horse_default = {1, 2, 3, 4};

int main(){
    int i;
    int a = sizeof(struct horse); //I want this to return the amount of members in the struct
    for(i = 0; i<a; i++){
        horse_1[i] = horse_default[i] + 2; //I want this to access the i-th member of the struct variable
    }

    printf("Horse age: %d\n", horse.age);
    printf("Horse height: %d\n", horse.height);
    printf("Horse width: %d\n", horse.width);
    printf("Horse weight: %d\n", horse.weight);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The short answer is: You can't. That's not what structs are for.

Comment: What you want is impossible in Standard C. But I believe you're posing a "XY problem"... ie... X is your problem; you think Y is the solution to X so you ask how to do Y... when in fact you want to do X.

Comment: You could use an array (if all items have the same type) and an `enum` enumerating the names of your structure. Then your data structure will be an array indexed by the `enum` values, like `horse_1[age]`. And if you name your last field `number_of_fields`, that is the --well-- number of fields. Decalre you horse like `int horse[number_of_fields]` then.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible, C language is a language without [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming).

You may write a separate program that processes the source code of your program and extracts the information that you want and modifies your source file or generates some separate C source code with required information, and then feeds all the result to a C compiler.

You may manually write and maintain accessors to each field using [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) or a big switch case. Such implementation look like:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct horse_s {
    int age;
    int height;
    int width;
    int weight;
};

static const size_t HORSE_MEMB_CNT = 4;

int *horse_get_memb(struct horse_s *t, size_t idx) {
     // using offsetof
     const size_t offsets[] = {
         offsetof(struct horse_s, age),
         offsetof(struct horse_s, height),
         offsetof(struct horse_s, width),
         offsetof(struct horse_s, weight),
     };
     static_assert(sizeof(offsets)/sizeof(*offsets) == HORSE_MEMB_CNT, "");
     assert(idx < HORSE_MEMB_CNT);
     return (int*)((char*)t + offsets[idx]);

     // using switch case
     switch (idx) {
     case 0: return &t->age;
     case 1: return &t->height;
     case 2: return &t->width;
     case 3: return &t->weight;
     default: assert(0);
     }
     return 0;
}

int main() {
    struct horse_s horse;
    *horse_get_memb(&horse, 2) = 42; // assigns to width
}
```

It may happen that your compiler is sane and will allocate structure members one after another. You could just cast it in such cases, but it breaks some language rules and should *not* be used and may not work.

```
static_assert(offsetof(struct horse_s, age) == 0, "");
static_assert(offsetof(struct horse_s, height) == sizeof(int) * 1, "");
static_assert(offsetof(struct horse_s, width) == sizeof(int) * 2, "");
static_assert(offsetof(struct horse_s, weight) == sizeof(int) * 3, "");
int *horsearr = (int*)&horse;
horsearr[2] = 42; // assigns to width
```

---

Anyway, if you want to initialize a structure with some defaults stored in some structure instance, then just initialize or assign the structure.

```
 const struct horse_s horse_default = { some defaults };
 int main() {
     struct horse_s horse = horse_default;
 }
```

Comment: You can pack the struct and guarantee that you can access it's members. You will still run afoul of strict aliasing rule (unless you memcpy values), but that is de-facto OK in a lot of code.

Comment: @4386427 Well, you might not want it, but someone who wants something akin to [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming) in C would definitely want something like this.  I've written code like this several times.

Comment: @SteveSummit Well, maybe I would if I could see when and how it was useful. Can you elaborate.

Comment: Okay.  Suppose I wrote this code:
`printf("cell? ");
scanf("%d", &i);
printf("new value? ");
scanf("%d", &v);
if(i == 0) a[0] = v;
else if(i == 1) a[1] = v;
else if(i == 2) a[2] = v;`

You'd say I was an idiot; you'd tell me to just make use of the array, and write `a[i] = v`.
Now: suppose you're DeepSeaTomToms, and you want to let the user
adjust the horse's age, height, width, or weight, and you *don't*
want to use the same sort of ugly if/else chain, you want to do
something cleaner and more generic.  How do you do it?

Comment: As you wrote in a comment, "That's not what structs are for", and you're right, but sometimes people legitimately want to treat a struct as if it were an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).  If your language supports [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming) on its user-defined data types, you can.

Comment: There are two differences between arrays and structs, as I think of it: (1) an array's keys are numeric; (2) an array's indices can be manipulated at run time, whereas a struct's keys can be used only at compile time.  Reflection offers you a way around both difficulties: it lets you do the moral equivalent of `struct horse h; char *key = "height"; h[key] = 12;`.  (And then there's a third big difference, of course: a struct's fields aren't necessarily all of the same type.  So to truly take advantage of data reflection, your language probably also needs some kind of a dynamic type system.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in C. It's a relatively low level language. sizeof returns the size of the structure in bytes, and [] is for pointer dereferencing.

The only way to do something similar to what you want is to use arrays. You can use constants for indexes to simulate named members.